# Calculating dn/ds ratio between two model organisms

Tags: r, biomart

I am trying to calculate the dn/ds ratio between the human genes and c.elegans. However, I am getting NA values in the output file

I used the following script

```
library(biomaRt)

## This gives the full list of all marts, including archives
archives <- listEnsemblArchives()

## For the c.elegans data
ensemblcelegans=useMart(host = 'jan2020.archive.ensembl.org', biomart = 
'ENSEMBL_MART_ENSEMBL', 
                 dataset = "celegans_gene_ensembl")

filters = listFilters(ensemblcelegans)
attributes = listAttributes(ensemblcelegans)

Celegans_GFList <- scan("c.elegans.tsv", what = character())
Celegans_GFListValues<-getBM(attributes = c('ensembl_gene_id', 
'hsapiens_homolog_ensembl_gene',  'hsapiens_homolog_dn', 
                                    'hsapiens_homolog_ds', 'hsapiens_homolog_orthology_type'), 
                     filters = 'ensembl_gene_id', 
                     values = Celegans_GFList, 
                     mart = ensemblcelegans)

Celegans_GFListValues1 <- subset(Celegans_GFListValues, 
Celegans_GFListValues$hsapiens_homolog_orthology_type == 'ortholog_one2one')
Celegans_GFListValues1$dnds_ratios <- 
Celegans_GFListValues1$hsapiens_homolog_dn/Celegans_GFListValues1$hsapiens_homolog_ds
write.csv(Celegans_GFListValues1, file = "Celegans_GFListValues.csv")
```

Comment: Hi @Tom, what did you do to debug the problem? Did you check what is the result of Celegans_GFListValues1$hsapiens_homolog_dn/Celegans_GFListValues1$hsapiens_homolog_ds or what is returned by getBM?

Comment: @IIrs I am getting NA values

Comment: So, is the data available on Celegans_GFListValues1 ?

Comment: The one to one ortholog data is present but dn and ds values are coming as NA for entire input list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensembl discontinued our calculation of dN/dS scores for orthologue pairs in release 100 (https://apr2020.archive.ensembl.org/index.html). However, even when we did perform these calculations in Ensembl 99 and earlier, we only did this for pairs of orthologues that diverged within the last ∼100 million years, namely between pairs of mammalian, avian or tetraodontiforme genomes. More information can be found here:

https://academic.oup.com/database/article/doi/10.1093/database/bav096/2630091

Comment: Thank you so much